# Оторвала́сь / Обозна́лась

Tags: орфоэпия, глаголы

В слове оторвала́сь ударение приходится на последний слог, а в слове обозна́лась - на предпоследний. Какие правила влияют на это?
Вроде бы, глаголы *рвать* и *знать* не имеют ничего, заставляющее по-разному строить слова, производные от них.

Answer (score 1):

**ОторвалАсь и обознАлась (неверно: оторвАлась).**

Пояснение

Глаголы делятся **на четыре акцентные группы** (при сравнении ударения во всех изменяемых формах): A (постоянное ударение на одном слоге основы), B и  C (ударение смещается с основы на окончание в разных формах), D (постоянное ударение на окончании).

**Особым явлением является смещение ударения на окончание  в форме ж.р. прош. времени**, его  могут иметь глаголы групп А, В, С.

Глагол ***знать*** из группы А: знаю, знает, знАла, знали. Как мы видим, **ударение постоянное, в том числе в форме ж.р.** Приставочная форма **обознАлась** тоже не имеет ж. ударения на окончании.

Глагол ***рвать*** (= разрывать): рвёт, рвут, **рвалА (ударение в ж. р. на окончании),** рвАли, рвАло. Приставочная форма также имеет ударение на окончании: **оторвалАсь**.

А вот ударение **оторвАлась** (перенос ударения с окончания на основу), которое встречается в разговорной речи, **ненормативно.**

**И вывод:**

1) Надо представлять себе общую картину ударений в глаголах. **Перенос ударения на окончание в ж.р. – это не общее свойство всех глаголов,** поэтому желательно внимательно отслеживать все приставочные и бесприставочные формы одного глагола, для которого такой перенос делается. В грамматике такие глаголы описываются по группам, но это информация большого объема.

2) Ударение желательно контролировать по словарю в тех случаях, если встречаются **речевые варианты.**

Comment: Jasmin, а как же быть с информацией из "Словаря трудностей..."?  Оторваться, оторвУсь, оторвётся; прош. оторвАлся (устарелое оторвалсЯ), оторвалАсь (**допустимо оторвАлась**), оторвалОсь, оторвалИсь (**допустимо оторвАлось, оторвАлись**). https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/5053/оторваться

Comment: Посмотрела у Резниченко (2009 год), там "оторвАла" - неправильно! А так что делать, просторечие теснит нормированный язык. Если все будут говорить "оторвАла", а потом и "рвАла", то и это признают нормой. Но Вы пока так не говорите, тогда еще продержимся.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае смещение ударения на последний слог (отн. мужского рода) позволяет различать на слух варианты среднего и женского рода, во втором случае это не нужно (средний род глагола практически не употребляется из-за "одушевлённости" смысла). Для сравнения: *отозва́ла́сь - отозвало́сь* (эхо).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А теперь, хотелось бы знать, какое правило влияет на то, чтобы была такая разница? 
Вряд ли есть правило  "для облегчения различения на слух". 
Оно же как-то прописано в русской лингвистике? 
И да, я бы не назвал ударение на последний слог смещением. Большинство подобных глаголов - как правило, и имеют такое ударение.
А вариант ,животное обозналось" - вполне осмысленно звучит.
Среднего рода слов, способных "обознаться" - вполне можно насобирать. Всё будет осмысленно.
Мне необходимо знать правило. Вопрос - об этом.

Comment: Вряд ли есть единое правило, скорее есть тенденция, которой обычно следует группа глаголов с тем или иным набором признаков. Можно, например, выделить группу _глаголов с приставками, односложными корнями и постфиксом -ся_ (см. в начале последней трети страницы): https://lampa.io/p/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-00000000a0d8069e277eb510d1ca31bd

Answer (score 0):

алекс, судя по самой постановке вопроса и вашим комментариям, вы не очень представляете, что в языке далеко не все можно объяснить "в лоб" на основании очевидных причинно следственных связей. 
В данном случае, если попытаться найти какое-то "правило" то придется уйти в историю возникновения современных форм прошедшего времени, а это такая седая древность, когда формы глаголов на "л" были причастиями, а инфинитив не основной формой глагола, а... особым дательным падежом. Да и само понятие ударения сильно отличалось от современного. Да и то вряд ли найдем что-то пригодное для объяснения.

Так уж сложилось, что часть глаголов требуют ударения на окончание - "рвал**а**" (если это вообще окончание), другая -"знала" - сохраняет фиксированное ударение на корне. Да ещё в процессе уже более современной истории ударение могло смещаться под действием плохо формализуемых причин. 
Возможно, что сказалось принципиальное различие в глаголах, один (рвать) типичный глагол действия, другой (знать)  - скорее глагол состояния. Но вряд ли это всеобъемлющее правило, такового в русском просто нет.

Всё, что могу добавить, это дать ссылку на замечательную лекцию  Андрея Зализняка, частично приоткрывающую завесу над тайнами русского исторического ударения.
https://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/432371/Iz_russkogo_udareniya

Comment: Я более двадцати пяти лет занимаюсь расшифровкой смыслового содержания слов, и много дискутирую с так называемыми филологами. Они позиционируют свою науку как очень точную, почти математику. Поэтому, "в лоб" - как раз по причине такого их заявления, если вы настаиваете на чём-либо, то предъявляйте на то прямые доказательства, а не беспомощное "так уж вышло", "так сложилось".
А этимология, вообще - вся на этом стоит, прослеживает лишь пути слов по странам, и совсем не занимается смыслом слов и их происхождением.

Comment: *Я ... занимаюсь расшифровкой смыслового содержания слов* - ну бог  в помощь ))). Я лет пятьдесят интересуюсь (непрофессионально) филологией - и не разу не встречал серьезного филолога, который бы "позиционировал" свою науку как точную.)))  Скорее всего вы просто на разных языках разговариваете. Под "доказательствами" лингвисты обычно разумеют ссылки на авторитетные источники или, "на крайняк" - собственные работы, на основании общепринятых **методов** сделанные. Так уж вышло - это не доказательство это намек на изначально  некорректную постановку вопроса так называемых "народных этимологов".